# Sails translation timestamp

Tags: javascript, html, sails.js, ejs

I'm currently working on Sails.js.

After a request on my database from my controller, I receive a timestamp.
I want to display this timestamp in my html.
I displayed the timestamp in the console (on the server), but once on my html page, instead of a timestamp, I have the date in full letters.
I would like to display the same string in the HTML WITHOUT translation.
How could I do this ?

Here is my code :

```
getClient: function(req, res) {
    myAPIname.find({idClient:'3'}).exec(function (err, client){
        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        var createdAt;
        client.forEach(function(clt){
        createdAt=clt.createdAt;
        })
        sails.log(createdAt);
        return res.view('myEJSpage',{
            createdAt
        });
    })
}
```

The return in the sails' console :

```
2017-03-21T07:33:30.000Z
```

The return in the sails' HTML

```
Tue Mar 21 2017 08:33:30 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) in EJS

E.g.

```
<%= createdAt.toISOString() %>
```